# How do I perform a search using the App bar?

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, android-searchmanager

So I'm trying to perform a search using the app bar and passing the query to an attribute I call "**searchRequest**". I want to display the result.

I have been following [this guide in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) and tried  But then I to no avail.

As I have commented out, my temporary solution is to call my loader and make the "searchRequest" a class attribute. But this seems to cause multiple problems such as the result remaining on the screen despite pressing the back button.

I have tried the override the `onOptionsMenuClosed()` method, setting an `setOnCloseListener()` to my searchView.

I suspect I should be doing this in a dedicated SearchActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            this.searchRequest = query;
            /*LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null,MainActivity.this);*/

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: check this tutorial http://instinctcoder.com/android-studio-sqlite-search-searchview-actionbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this too, This will get called whenever search view expands or collapse.

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchView,
                    new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            // Refresh here with full list.
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: This is exactly want I was looking for! Thank you!